# Documentation: Fee Bump - 10x vs 10%

Tags: fees, developersguide

While reading the following - I wanted to confirm if the second transaction should have fee of 10x (10 times) or 10% higher (1.10 times) than the fee of the first transaction.

if first-fee = 100
1/ second-fee = first-fee * 10 = 1000 [10x]
2/ second-fee = first-fee + 10% * first-fee = 110 [10%]

as per the developer docs here:
https://developers.stellar.org/docs/tutorials/handling-errors/

If you submit two distinct transactions with the same source account and sequence number, and the second transaction is a fee-bump transaction, the second transaction will be included in the transaction queue in place of the first transaction if and only if the fee bid of the second transaction is at least 10x the fee bid of the first transaction.